# jest to continue checking expect() even after error

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am a newbie in testing. 
I am having issues in test.
my test quit immediately after its gets first not matched and does not check the remaining expectations

I would like to jest to finish testing each expectations even after it occur error or unexpected value

```
test("concrete scope test should pass", async () => {

  const scale = funcs.getScale(theJson);

  const concreteScopes = await s.getConcreteScope(
    theJson,
    lines,
    scale,
    data.scopeId,
    order.pdf
  );
  expect(concreteScopes.ScopeId).toBe(33);
  expect(concreteScopes.Name).toEqual(theJson.Name);
  expect(concreteScopes.Address).toEqual(theJson.Address);
  expect(concreteScopes.PDF).toEqual("dfa");

}, 300000);
```

I have errors in first expect `expect(concreteScopes.ScopeId).toBe(33);` and in last expect `expect(concreteScopes.PDF).toEqual("dfa");`

but it terminates at first error and does not show me the remaining errors

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 33
    Received: "275188"

      45 |     order.pdf
      46 |   );
    > 47 |   expect(concreteScopes.ScopeId).toBe(33);
         |                                  ^
      48 |   expect(concreteScopes.Name).toEqual(theJson.Name);
      49 |   expect(concreteScopes.Address).toEqual(theJson.Address);
      50 |   expect(concreteScopes.PDF).toEqual("dfa");

      at Object.toBe (__test__/concretescope.test.js:47:34)`
```

It does not show error at line 50 (btw the values in between 48, 49 are correct).

Answer (score 3):

Jest will terminate after one assertion fails. This is to support the idea that [a test should assert exactly one thing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7823/is-it-ok-to-have-multiple-asserts-in-a-single-unit-test/7825). It's not necessarily bad to have multiple related assertions in a single test, but if your unit test tests a single piece of functionality and one assertion fails, it doesn't really matter if the others are correct or not. If you need to figure out what's wrong with your test result, just debug or console.log concreteScopes.

Comment: `concreteScopes` is returning an object it has some mathematical calculation values which needs match some of our own calculated values so how can i have a multiple test for the same function ?

Comment: @MuhammadSharif I wasn't saying you should write multiple tests for this function, I wouldn't know whether or not your assertions were related. From what you're saying it sounds like they are. My point was that you can't continue jest execution after one assertion fails. You need to figure out why the first assertion failed

Answer (score 1):

Wow this is old, but maybe it helps someone else getting started, here goes.

I'm not arguing against apoteet - the sentiment that a unit test should test one thing is very, very sound.  Also the timeout is *300* seconds, which is worrying for most any kind of automated test.

However, jest can easily facilitate more advanced testing than pure single unit testing, but no matter what - running one action and having a more complete scope of the result of that action without needing to debug or log can be a time saving habit in and of itself!

To this question, you can use toMatchObject to get the full scope of your expectation, something like:

```
expect(concreteScopes).toMatchObject({
  ScopeId: 33,
  Name: theJson.Name,
  Address: theJson.Address,
  PDF: "dfa",
});
```

Notably, .toMatchObject(expected) only compares the properties defined in the expected object, so concreteScopes can be a giant object, but this test will only confirm those four values match.