# Jest aggregating failures

Tags: jestjs

In Ruby (with RSpec) there is a feature called [aggregating failures](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/expectation-framework-integration/aggregating-failures) that allows you to group a set of expectations and see all the failures at once.

I was wondering if there is a similar feature with Jest. It seems that the framework does not provide this but maybe someone knows a library

Comment: probably it is not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57065326/jest-to-continue-checking-expect-even-after-error